# can't install angular cli on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: angular-cli

I am on an ssh connection to an ubuntu 16.04 system I have npm 3.10.10 installed, when I try to install angular cli some progress is made and then I am only left with one line of error code, as follows:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:~# npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
[killed.....] | extract:@angular/cli: sill doParallel extract 678
```

Comment: Please do 'npm install -g @angular/cli --verbose' and post the result. You can try using '--force' though its better to figure out what's causing the issue.